# Zip entry name ends in directory separator character but contains data

Tags: c#, exception, extract, zip

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

Using ZipFile in C#, I'm trying to extract a file from a known location and it is throwing the following error:
System.IO.Exception: Zip entry name ends in directory separator character but contains data

I've done some research, ExtractToDirectory is explained in MSDN but couldn't find this error definition. Would you be able to explain why this error is happening?

From MSDN:

IOException

> The directory specified by destinationDirectoryName already exists.

-or-

The name of an entry in the archive is Empty, contains only white space, or contains at least one invalid character.

-or-

> Extracting an archive entry would create a file that is outside the directory specified by destinationDirectoryName. (For example, this might happen if the entry name contains parent directory accessors.)

-or-

> An archive entry to extract has the same name as an entry that has already been extracted from the same archive.

Comment: I guess this essentially means the filename stored in the zip archive either contains `..` or ends in a `\`. Are you sure you don't somehow mess the paths, e.g. using the target path as the zip archive internal path?

Comment: One thing that I found out after spending couple of hours is that this issue is related with the way the zip file generated.

For the issue to happen, I generated the zip file with 7-zip. Generating the zip file using winRar resolved the issue.

I still don't know the root cause of it though.

Comment: @Mario, That was my initial guess as well. However I haven't found any issues regarding the paths (Thanks for the comment though).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My research shows that when you compress the files with 7-Zip utility using "Ultra" compression level, certain archives cannot be unzipped with .NET System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory() method.
The error message is: Zip entry name ends in directory separator character but contains data.

Based on my observation, this error occurs only if the following 3 conditions are met:

1. The target archive is large - 500MB+ (Small archives seem to unzip fine).
2. The root of the archive contains ONLY FOLDERS (if you add at least one file to the root of the archive it also unzips fine).
3. 7-Zip Ultra compression is used.

---

In the end I found three solutions to this 7-Zip bug.

**Solution 1**: Add at least one file to the root of the archive (any dummy file or a readme.txt file).

**Solution 2**: Use native Windows compression utility (Select files, right-click, Send To -> Compressed folder).

**Solution 3**: Do not use 7-Zip Ultra compression.

All of these solutions resolved the problem for me. Pick the one that fits your project best.

Comment: Another possible condition I have found - if you're using 7zip to compress something that is on a mounted drive (but native on OSX). I have a VM where I am working in Windows, but the drive is being shared between the two OSes. Solution 2 fixed this particular problem.

Comment: I have a .zip file created with 7z, using the option `-tzip`, which is equivalent to `-tzip -mm=Deflate -mx=5`, i.e. it is not using 7-zip ultracompression.  Also, I placed a file in the foot of the archive.  The file _is_ large, 600MB+, containing 45000 files in 36 dirs.  I opened the zip file using `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open` in a debugger.  Among all 36 dirs entries, all terminate with "/", but only two show a non-zero length, and this length is completely non-sensical.  The result is that System.IO.Compression.ZipFile is unable to uncompress the file - i.e. soln 1 & 3 don't work.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when a ZipArchive entry ends with the directory separator character '/' but has a Length != 0

You can easily find these entries with

```
zip.Entries.Where(o => o.FullName.EndsWith("/") && o.Length != 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  The question I have is where is this non-zero length coming from?  All directories in the zip archive end with "/", but all should have length 0.  Very occasionally, some do not have length zero, and in those cases the length seems completely meaningless.  Do you have any idea if the fault lies in the archive that 7z.exe produces, or does the fault lie in `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open` ??

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh I can't imagine that ZipFile.Open is some how modifying the contents of the zip.  Its much more likely that it's caused by an external zip program which causes this.  This should be easy to verify by making a copy of the zip file prior to ZipFile.Open and comparing the original to the open file to ensure it wasn't modified.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. By "does the fault lie in `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open`", I wasn't questioning if it modifies the .zip file.  We are seeing the "non-zero" length in the data structure that `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open` builds when it reads in the zip file, but it is not clear to me if it is actually bad data in the file, or if `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open` has a bug that causes it to build the data structure internally with an incorrect length entry.

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh The only time i've seen the problem it was due to bad files.  I haven't seen any problems with .NET's handling of the data.  The zip file format isn't too bad to identify the file headers and verify the length is non-zero with a binary editor.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle this problem and even some package like sharpZip do not works. (problem appear in TeamCity and artefact zip package)

End up this solusion using SharpCompress(https://www.nuget.org/packages/sharpcompress/)

```
var archive = ArchiveFactory.Open(model.UserParams.PathToZipFile.FullName);

foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
{
  if (entry.IsDirectory == false)
  {
   entry.WriteToDirectory(unZipDirectory, new ExtractionOptions() { ExtractFullPath = true, Overwrite = true });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 6 (and earlier?) there appears to be a bug when reading some zip archives (as others have mentioned, I've seen this with *some* 7zip archives) where the `Length` and `CompressedLength` properties are read incorrectly.

This results in those properties being set to 4294967295 (~4GB) for ALL entries (directories and files alike).  On extraction, this results in the error that's seen:

```
System.IO.Exception: Zip entry name ends in directory separator character but contains data
```

This bug has been fixed in .NET 7+ and the file lengths are set properly.